Beta-plus decay, a many-body problem?
In the beta-plus decay, a proton turns into a neutron, a positron, and a neutrino.
But the mass of a proton is less than a neutron. This of course indicates that an isolated proton is stabel against beta-plus decay.
The beta-plus decay thus must happen in a nucleus where multiple protons and neutrons are present. It must be a many-body problem, while the beta decay could be a single-body problem.
Does this mean that beta-plus is weaker, or slower than beta decay?
